Is the term オタク considered offensive?
I have seen the term オタク appear in many different places, referring to people very into some hobby (usually anime, manga, computers, gaming, or related). However, I'm not sure if it's a derogatory or offensive term if said of someone in particular, i.e., あの人はオタクだ. I'm an anime fan myself, so I would like to know whether this is slightly offensive if someone said this to me.

As written, this is a question about the use of the word in English, and not Japanese.

@jogloran My question is asking about whether it is offensive in Japan. Sorry for any misunderstandings. Do you suggest any ways to improve my question?

FWIW Wiktionary claims “The term has recently gained derogatory connotations in its mainstream usage,” but I don’t know how up-to-date and/or trustworthy this is. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AF

@JoshGrosso As far as I remember, it never "gained" derogatory connotations anywhere in the history of the word. It was worst when it was created...

It started off as an extremely derogatory word. In the 1980s, when the term オタク became recognized, it was described by the media as referring to mentally unstable potential criminals who could not lead a normal social life. If anime VHS tapes were found in a criminal's home, it was common for the media to report it as "Another otaku crime!" Miyazaki Tsutomu was the public image of this term.
As of 2024, however, this is no longer the case at all. Now, more than half of the younger generation proudly identifies themselves as otaku, and very few people associate anime/manga fandom with crimes or anything negative. People generally use other words to insult others. Many Japanese municipalities are utilizing anime for town revitalization.
Whether saying "あの人はオタクだ" is considered insulting depends on the context. If the speaker is an otaku themselves, it would be taken as "He's one of us". If the speaker still holds strong prejudices against otaku, it will sound pejorative, although this is not very common these days.
Please also read: Are there any terms used to refer to people of the anime/manga fandom in a non-derogatory manner?

It's similar to "nerd" in English - I might call myself a nerd, but at the same time might see a "normie" calling me a nerd as being an insult.

Thanks, your answer is exactly what I'm looking for. It seems like there's quite a drastic change in recent years. Anyway, I also agree with you and @ConMan that it mainly depends on the person saying this. If the person is a オタク themselves, then it's absolutely OK. But if the person is biased against オタク, then it's not so good. Again,  thanks for your answer! It helped a lot.
